# How to decode JSON array as property of struct with JSONDecoder

Tags: swift, decodable

I had data struct like this

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "profile": [
        {
            "type": "name",
            "value": "Hellow"
        },
        {
            "type": "email",
            "value": "1@a.com"
        },
    ]
}
```

Now I could decode it like this

```
struct Profile: Decodable {
    let version: Int
    let name: String
    let email: String
    struct Item: Decodable {
        let type: String
        let value: String
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        version = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .version)
        let items = try container.decode([Item].self, forKey: .data)
        name = items.first{$0.type == "name"}!.value
        email = items.first{$0.type == "email"}!.value
    }
}
```

Does there are any way to update Profile without rewrite init(from)?

**Update**
`@dynamicMemberLookup` can use like mapping function.
But it will lose autocomplete.

```
@dynamicMemberLookup
struct Profile: Decodable {
    let version: Int
    
    struct Item: Decodable {
        let type: Keys
        let value: String
    }
    let profile: [Item]
    
    enum Keys: String, Decodable, ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
        case name
        case email
        case undefined
        
        init(stringLiteral: String) {
            self = Keys(rawValue: stringLiteral) ?? .undefined
        }
    }
    
    subscript(dynamicMember member: Keys) -> String {
        return profile.first{$0.type == member}?.value ?? "undefined"
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with writing `init(from:)`? Do you have a lot of other properties to decode?

Comment: It’s pretty simple: The more customization you want the more code you have to write. There is no other way because you have to tell the decoder how to map the original data structure to your custom one. However you could write a mapping function **after**  decoding the data.

Comment: You could have `struct Profile: Decodable { let version Int; private let items: [Item]}`. You "hide" `items` to the others and no need for override of `init(from:)`. Then, you can use a computed property or a lazy var to get `name` and email: `var name: String { items.first { $0.type == "name"}!.value }`, and the same for `email`.